# How to match column of two tables in sqlite and depending on matching how to retrieve data?

Tags: android

This is my two tables-

```
private static final  String SQL_CREATE_RETAIL_DB_PRODUCT =
                        "CREATE TABLE " + DatabaseContract.RetailDatabaseEntry.TABLE_NAME_PRODUCT + " (" +
                                DatabaseContract.RetailDatabaseEntry.COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                                DatabaseContract.RetailDatabaseEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_ID + INTEGER_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                                DatabaseContract.RetailDatabaseEntry.COLUMN_NAME + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                                DatabaseContract.RetailDatabaseEntry.COLUMN_IMAGE + BLOB_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                                DatabaseContract.RetailDatabaseEntry.COLUMN_QUANTITY + INTEGER_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                                DatabaseContract.RetailDatabaseEntry.COLUMN_PRICE + INTEGER_TYPE +
                                        " )";
private static final  String SQL_CREATE_RETAIL_DB_SCAN =
                        "CREATE TABLE " + DatabaseContract.RetailDatabaseEntry.TABLE_NAME_SCAN + " (" +
                                DatabaseContract.RetailDatabaseEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCTID_ID + INTEGER_TYPE + ")";
```

I want to match the column productid of product table with productid of scan table.
And depending on matching i have to retrieve data.

Please suggest me solution as I am new to android.

Answer (score 0):

Retrive the value of product id from first table and do query on second table with where clause example select * from  where productid = (product id of first table)

Comment: how to get value of product id from first table in select query.I don't know as i m new to sqlite database in android.

Comment: u told me how to retrieve the data.but tell me how to match this both column.

Comment: DatabaseHelper dbhelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);

Comment: dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
   db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
   Cursor cursor = db.query(TableName,null, null, null, null, null, null);
   while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
   {
    
    productId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(productId));
   }

Comment: You can use product id in second table like this                                db.query(TableName,null, "productId = ?", new String[]{productId of first table}, null, null, null);                                                              if(cursor.moveToFirst()){                                                                    get all column value

Comment: will u help me with proper code.As i m trying the solution which u have given,but i m not getting any thing.